# Download specific image from website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, image, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to download an image from a website using BeautifulSoup.

This is a snippet of the HTML from the website that's relevant:

```
<div class="c-image _verticalMode">
    <div class="c-image__inner">
        <img src="https://images.example.com/qwe098.jpg/dims/optimize" class="c-image__image" width="100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how much I've written so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url=r'https://www.example.com/d?tNo=123&aNo=17'

soup=bs(requests.get(url).content,'html.parser')
pics=soup.find(class_='c-image')
print(pics)
```

This prints out:

```
<div class="c-image _verticalMode">
<!--
        <div class="c-image__inner">
          <img src="../../img/c/dummy.jpg" class="c-image__image" width="100%">
        </div>
        -->
<!--
        <a href="#" class="c-img__prev"><i class="i-arrow-left-black"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="c-img__next"><i class="i-arrow-right-black"></i></a>
      -->
</div>
```

The img src is truncated (due to BeautifulSoup?), but it doesn't look like it's the same as the location given in the first HTML snippet (though it is in the same location).

I can't seem to manage to get the link. I've tried to use `soup.find(class_='c-image__image')`, but that returns a NoneType object.

What can I do to get the right image link, so that I can download it?

Comment: I can't open your link, but by viewing your code, those image tags are in HTML comments, so beautifulsoup reads it as text content, not a tag. They are in `<!-- ... -->`

Comment: Your URL `https://www.example.com/d?tNo=123&aNo=17` gives `404 - Not Found` for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working strictly off of your html snippet in the question:

```
my_img = """[your html snippet]"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(my_img,'lxml')
pics=soup.select_one('div.c-image__inner img')
print(pics['src'])
```

Output:

```
https://images.example.com/qwe098.jpg/dims/optimize
```